# Can we create dojo declarative(not programatic) titlePane inside template based widget?

Tags: dojo

Can we create dojo declarative  titlePane inside template based widget?

When I am creating a titlePane out side the template file like :

It is working, but as soon as I have moved this code to html template file it is not working. (I am attachiong this file to dojo widget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add widgets in your template yes. There are only a few things you have to remind:

- You can not use a widget as the root element of the template,
- You should inherit from the `dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin` as well,
- Like all declarative markup, you still have to include the module itself (`dijit/TitlePane`), by adding it either to your `require()` or `define()`.
  For example:

```js
declare("my/Widget", [ _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin ], {
    title: "My title",
    content: "My content",
    templateString: "<div>" +
    "<div data-dojo-type=\"dijit/TitlePane\" data-dojo-props=\"title: '${title}'\">${content}</div>" +
    "</div>"
});
```

I also made an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wVeVm/).